# Verb for "recreation"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a verb that specifically means *enjoy some recreation*?

I heard today (TV reference) a boss tell an employ to take a vacation, to "relax and recreate" (pronounced as the beginning of recreation).

I've never heard this used before, and never really considered it a word.

A couple online searches have yielded what I expected - recreate only as meaning "to create again", or "to re-enact".

If this is not actually a word in this sense, is there a single verb meaning to *enjoy/experience recreation*?

Comment: I have used recreate in that sense, though there was context that indicated the meaning.  I think it is a reasonable construction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Recreate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recreate)* can mean *take recreation* as listed in Merriam-Webster. You can also consider using *refresh*, *rejuvenate*, *revitalize* or *recharge (your batteries)* for example.

Answer (score 2):

Although we don't often use the word in an adult context, the verb *play* may be appropriate. Its definition according to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/play):

> To act in a manner such that one has fun; to engage in activities
>   expressly for the purpose of recreation.